# Base URL connection string from SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have been asked to create a process where we can update multiple user records on a cloud hosted database, using data taken from one of our applications, hosted on site.  The connection to the hosted db requires the unique ID for the username to be specified as part of the base URL in a http connection, meaning only one user record can be updated at any one time, no bulk update option.

In our application, I can create the Base URL connection string and add this to a field in the Users table (SQL Server), plus I have the unique ID for the username in the same table.

The format of the Base URL is: -
https://api.hosteddb.com/v1.svc/users/1234567890abcdefg?source=application.hosteddb.com

Our tool of choice is Visual Studio 2017, which I have used several times before.  In VS, I have tried to create an Execute SQL Task so I can set the parameter to the base URL in the Users table but I cant get this working.

How do pass the Base URL from multiple records on our Users table and set the http connection to each one is passed, the record is updated, then the next Base URL is set in the http connection?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Kieran

Answer (score 0):

While I don't get all of your needs, the general pattern you're looking for is

### Execute SQL Task

Define an execute sql task that has a full resultset as your return type and pull back the baseurl (and another other columns you may need).

```
SELECT BaseUrl FROM dbo.MyTable
```

Push the results of that in an SSIS variable of type Object, which I will call `rsObject.` Name it as you wish.

### Foreach Loop Container

Add a foreach loop (not a for loop) to your control flow as a successor task. Configure the foreach loop to use an ADO.NET recordset. It doesn't not matter whether you used an OLEDB, ADO.NET or ODBC connection manager in the previous step, the enumerator type you want is ADO.NET Recordset.

In the Variables/Mapping tab (doing this from memory), you will need to provide more SSIS variables so a variable called `baseUrl` would go to ordinal position 0, and so on.

At this point run the package. The Foreach loop should flicker and when it's done, it stays green. This confirms that the Execute SQL Task works as expected and you have "shredded" the result set. (An internet search for "SSIS Shred Resultset" should provide many examples of how to wire up this task)

### Web task

Put a http/web task inside the Foreach Loop. In the web task, configure it to point to your supplied URL so the basic design works.

What we then need to do is assign an `Expression` to the URL property to make the URL value change in sync with the variable baseUrl. Right click on the Task and choose Properties. From the Properties, find Expressions. In the list of properties we can assign, find one that sounds like the Url and in the value column use `@[User::baseUrl]`

At this point, each enumeration through the list generated in the first step will update baseUrl. When the Execute web task thing fires, it will "know" to use the current value of the baseUrl.